# Зачем в Android Studio два визуальных представления лэйаута?

Tags: android-studio

В Android Studio зачем-то имеются две картинки-представления xml-лэйаута. Зачем они нужны?

Answer (score 3):

Имеется два режима, [Design и Blueprint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html). Можете работать с каждым как в отдельности , так и сразу с обоими.

Design режим отображает расположение View-шек как они выглядят на экране устройства. Blueprint режим отображает контуры View-шек, особенно полезно когда они накладываются друг на друга.